# Как вывести цикл новостей в разные div

Tags: laravel

Делаю вывод новостей на страницу
И мне нужно вывести новости на страницу в блоки которые выглядят так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать это через foreach?

Comment: Тебе придется сделать несколько foreach... иного вариянта нет. Максимум пять штук тебе надо сделать, начиная сверху 2 цикла, внизу уже один цикл, либо тебе придется поминать свой шаблон на новостях или же дайте знать если есть другой вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании директивы `@foreach` в шаблонизаторе Laravel доступна переменная `$loop`, одним из свойств которой является `index`, содержащий номер текущей итерации, начинающийся с **0**. Судя по изображении в вопросе нас интересует второй блок, следовательно, искомый индекс должен равняться 1:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @if (1 == $loop->index)
        <div>Это второй блок с записью.</div>
    @else
        <div>Это блок #{{ $post->id }}.</div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```